# Software upgrade broke camera

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a python script that turns the camera into a webcam. Today I did an upgrade:

```
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc6-dbg armhf 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [6377 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc-devtools armhf 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [245 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc6-dev armhf 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [1813 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc-dev-bin armhf 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [266 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc6 armhf 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [2297 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc-bin armhf 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [682 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf bluez armhf 5.55-3.1+rpt1 [843 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc-l10n all 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [863 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf locales all 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1 [4084 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libraspberrypi-dev armhf 1:2+git20210719~113532+97bc818-3 [180 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libraspberrypi-doc all 1:2+git20210719~113532+97bc818-3 [1564 B]
Get:12 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libraspberrypi-bin armhf 1:2+git20210719~113532+97bc818-3 [40.8 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libraspberrypi0 armhf 1:2+git20210719~113532+97bc818-3 [177 kB]
```

After rebooting, now when I run the script, I get

```
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.camera_info': Function not implemented
```

To reiterate: Nothing changed other than the upgraded list of packages above. Which one broke the camera and how do I fix it?

I un- and re-installed picamera, and that was no help. There is no conflicting version that I can find:

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pkg_resources import require
>>> require('picamera')
[picamera 1.13 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages)]
>>> require('picamera')[0].version
'1.13'
```

Comment: Some reported that `sudo mv /opt/vc /opt/oldvc`; `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi-bin` solved the 
"function not implemented"-problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the version of libraspberrypi0 that was installed in the upgrade. Manually downgrading to libraspberrypi0_1.20210831-1_armhf.deb fixed it.

EDIT: This has been *confirmed as a bug* in libraspberrypi0.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/pull/714

It is fixed in libraspberrypi0 1:2+git20211125~155417+14b90ff-1.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi's camera interface stack has changed in the Bullseye version of Debian/Raspberry Pi OS. In short, it's moving to line up with standard Linux APIs (*V4L2* and *libcamera*). More information can be found here: https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bullseye-camera-system/

Comment: That's as may be, but this still happens even when you re-enable the legacy stack. https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/705 https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/pull/714